# How to check NaN in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

How to check NaN value using xpath3 in mule.

I tried to do this but not getting result correct

```
#[xpath3('total',payload,'NUMBER')!='NaN'?xpath3('total',payload,'NUMBER'):0]
```

But not working

How can I check NaN value in mule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **is** or **instance of**, for example `#[xpath3('total',payload,'NUMBER') is java.lang.Number ? xpath3('total',payload,'NUMBER') : 0]`

Based on further testing, by using the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <total>100</total>
</data>
```

We can utilize **isNaN()** method, because the payload is a **java.lang.Double**. Therefore we can use the following MEL: `#[xpath3('//total',payload,'NUMBER').isNaN() ? 0 : xpath3('//total',payload,'NUMBER')]`

It can be tested through the following simple flow:

```
<flow name="simpleFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="#[xpath3('//total',payload,'NUMBER').isNaN() ? 0 : xpath3('//total',payload,'NUMBER')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Change the value of **total** field with a non numeric for testing purpose, e.g.: `<data><total>hundred</total></data>`

Comment: Not working.. I got this error: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 15 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision. (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException). Message payload is of type: ElementNSImpl (org.mule.api.MessagingException)